# I need to show the validity of the below arguments by using a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I need to show the validity of

$P \rightarrow Q$

$P \rightarrow R$

$\therefore  P \rightarrow (R \wedge Q)$

Can i just show the truth table for $P \rightarrow Q$ and the truth table for $P\rightarrow R$ then the truth table for $P \rightarrow (R \wedge Q)$
I think the truth table for $P \rightarrow (R \wedge Q)$ is:
T
T
F
T
F
T

Answer (score 5):

Use three columns, on the left most part of the truth-table, to keep track of the truth value assignments for $p, r, q$, one column per variable. So you need $2^3 = 8$ rows in your truth table, below the headings. Instead of creating three truth tables, create one truth-table, using a column for each premise, $p \rightarrow q$ and $p\rightarrow r$, and a final column for the conclusion: $p \rightarrow (q \land r)$.

For your argument to be valid, it must be the case that whenever all the premises are true, the conclusion must be true. So your truth table needs to show that whenever the premises $(p \rightarrow q)$ and $(p \rightarrow r)$ are *both* true, then so is be the conclusion $p \rightarrow (r \wedge q)$ true.

The following truth-table was generated by Wolfram Alpha. Be sure to check whether the condition of validity is met.

[image: The column of truth values for the eight possible rows will need to have $8$ entries in the column, not just $6$.]

Comment: Such a nice truth table! =1

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking one could make the analysis be a bit more concise if one simply tested the sentence $ [ ( p \to q ) \wedge ( p \to r ) ] \to [ p \to ( q \wedge r ) ] $?

Comment: $TTTTTTTT$ for my dear friend. +)

Comment: @cw.chambers  Concise?  There are only finitely many rows.  How much more concise could you be?

Answer (score 0):

An argument is valid if whenever all the premises are true, the conclusion must be true. So, the easiest thing is to compare the truth table of $(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (p \rightarrow r)$ with $p \rightarrow (r \wedge q)$.

Wolfram alpha can check your work: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28p+implies+q%29+and+%28p+implies+r%29) are the two premises and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28p+implies+%28r+and+q%29%29) is the conclusion. I strongly encourage you to do the truth table yourself, and then use this as a check. Remember that when the premises are true, the conclusion must be true if the argument is valid.

Answer (score -1):

$p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \vee q$
$p \rightarrow r \equiv \neg p \vee r$
$(p \rightarrow q ) \wedge ( p \rightarrow r ) \equiv ( \neg p \vee q ) \wedge ( \neg p \vee r)$  [reverse distribution property]
$(\neg p \vee (q \wedge r))$
$p \rightarrow  (q \wedge r)$

Comment: Note that the Question asks about using [truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to validate an argument.